# how google map draw on canvas in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

can anybody tell me or send me some links if there is any..which tells how Google map draw on canvas in android. what is the logic behind that.

any help will be highly appreciative.

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to download the Google APIs to start. You will then need to tell your project to use the APIs, specifically maps. You can follow the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).